# what size to use for background?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to use an image of backgrounds, but I do not know that size must be set for different size android, there are several specification is that you can tell me that you need to use size in pixels . for my application

Comment: Does the background image is like tiles which can be repeated ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/your_selected_background_image"
 >
```

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` attributes in your main layout will fill the background of your app with the image that you have selected completely on any device.

Comment: you are welcome @diez. Let me know if this is what you wanted. in my opinion this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NinePatch Image.

A NinePatch is a PNG image in which you can define stretchable regions that Android scales when content within the View exceeds the normal image bounds. You typically assign this type of image as the background of a View that has at least one dimension set to "wrap_content", and when the View grows to accomodate the content, the Nine-Patch image is also scaled to match the size of the View

```
<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/myninepatch" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch

Answer (score 0):

According to the android developer documents fill_parent is renamed as match_parent in API Level 8 and higher and it is recommend to use match_parent instead of fill_parent.
   math_parent/fill_parent can make the View's size stretch to its parent's size,so if you using android:layout_width="math_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent" in your background layout. Your background image will be automatically stretch to the size of your screen size(Accurately, it is depend on its parent's size).
   wrap_content make the view's size just big enough to enclose its cotent. So using wrap_content the view's size and its background will stretch depending on the view's content.